# 2 dropdowns - option on 1st removes options on 2nd

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have two selects - "segment" and "interest" with options.

I want to remove specific options from 2nd menu with value on 1st menu.
If I call
`$("#interest option[value='forhim']").remove();`

it removes this option but in the example bellow, it doesn't work/remove.

```
<script>
$('#segment').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'forher'){ // forher is value in #segment which should remove value forhim '
      $("#interest option[value='forhim']").remove();
    }
}); 
</script>
```

HTML

```
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"> 
                            <select class="dropdown" name="segment" id="segment" tabindex="1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                <option value="" <?php if($segment == "") echo "selected"; ?> >For who?</option>
                                <option value="forher" <?php  if($segment == "forher") echo "selected"; ?> >forher</option>
                                <option value="forhim" <?php  if($segment == "forhim") echo "selected"; ?> >forhim</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"> 
                            <select class="dropdown" name="interest" id="interest" tabindex="1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                <option value="" <?php if($interest == "") echo "selected"; ?> >Person type</option>
                                <option value="forhim" <?php  if($interest == "forhim") echo "selected"; ?> >For him</option>
                                <option value="sport" <?php  if($interest == "sport") echo "selected"; ?> >Sport</option>
                                <option value="tehno" <?php  if($interest == "tehno") echo "selected"; ?> >Techno</option>
                            </select>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/0zxxrmta/1/

Thanks for help!

Comment: Didi you check whether your condition is pass or not?

Comment: `alert("Yes it pass :)");`

Bu

Comment: Can you add your HTML as well?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a list of `if` I prefer this way to solve the problem.

Here you can see the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/afilini/vt2yk7oa/1/

Javascript code:

```
$('#segment').change(function(){
    var table = [];
    table['forhim'] = 'forher'; //This means: when i select what is between [ ] (in this case forhim), remove what is after the = (in this case forher). You can add multiple rules like this one

    $("#interest option[value='" + table[$(this).val()] + "']").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare value attribute for your select option.

**HTML:**

```
<select id="segment">
   <option>Select</option>
   <option>forher</option>
</select>
<select id="interest">
   <option>Select</option>
   <option value="forhim">forhim</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#segment').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'forher'){ // forher is value in #segment which should remove value forhim '
      $("#interest option[value='forhim']").remove();
    }
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/3m524vw0/

Answer (score 0):

Not much info to go on, but my guess is that you need to use `$(document).ready`. They way you have it as an inline `<script>`, the script may try to attach the `change` event handler to a dom element that is not yet added.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#segment').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'forher'){ 
    $("#interest option[value='forhim']").remove();
  }
 }); 
});
```

Comment: Most probably it should be the issue but HunterListInsight said that his condition is met :(

Comment: This solution works if you're not using the easy dropdown plugin. See fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rk8e4vwh/1/. This plugin uses hidden select boxes and renders a fancier view. your script removes the element from the hidden select, but not from the visible select box.